# Store big JSON in Titanium for iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, database, json, titanium

### How the app works

Currently an app is in the works which utility is to explore activities in 5 regions. Each activity is represented as an JS object with a fair amount of properties. Activities can be viewed through different filters in their respective tab, for example categories or a map. Inside each main filter, there are options to filter on date, region, accessibility etc.

### The challenge

There is a lot of JSON that needs to be stored on the device, and support is required for both **iOS and android**.
In the best case scenario the data needs to be in sync with the database, and all data needs to be available on the device. The app will need to be snappy for a good experience, this means that fetching data needs to be as fast as possible. Furthermore, filtering data needs to be as snappy as possible.

### Viable solutions considered so far (which don't quite cut it yet)

**[MongloDB](https://github.com/Monglo) with the [MongloDB Titanium Store adapter](https://github.com/Monglo/MongloDB-Titanium-Store), silver bullet?**

This approach at first seemed be the silver bullet. Although the project seems promising, it is maintained by one heroic hacker, and the project is in need of some documentation. I have inspected the source, and hacked my way through the API, but to no avail, console.log and jasmine tests won't cut it this time. More important still, it is not quite finished yet, and features compared to MongoDB are missing. A great project, I hope it will catch on more and be capable enough to assist desperate titanium developers in the future.

**[JSONDB](https://github.com/irlgaming/jsondb-public/blob/master/faq.md), only for iOS**

This app really needs to work on both platforms, iOS and android, so no reason for trying this. Moreover, JSONDB works within a single context only, which would be a serious concern as well.

**Ti Filesystem and JSON.stringify + JSON.parse, not memory efficient**

A viable solution for saving a small list of saved items, which is also a feature in the app. But in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865621/how-to-parse-a-big-json-file-in-android) issues over memory limits with the use of JSON methods have been noticed for android. Though this might not be the least of my problem, memory efficiency overal will be a huge problem. Never have I seen benchmarks for performance with file reading and writing for Titanium, so I am not sure how big of an impact reading and writing would be. Filtering big objects is a huge concern as well, [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) won't manage this kind of big data.  Iterating big objects is a huge problem no matter what approach I will choose.

**Big ass global object**

Practically the same approach as a Filesystem, only keep it in a global. This has the same issues and is just a plain unethical practice.

**SQLite, yuck**

Highly document oriented JSON data to SQlite, it sounds worse than samsung galaxy fanboys. Any feedback on this?

**Multiple files + SQLite to maintain + lazy load, unicorns and rainbows?**

Desperate for a solution, I might be onto something in the course of writing this post. There are probably something 10-16 main categories which each 1 to 4 subcategories. Keep all the activities for a subcategory in it's own file, which is a quite slim JSON. Browsing through categories, each subcategory is rendered in it's own TableViewSection, each subcategory be appended independently to the table based on how much the user is scrolled down, effectively lazy loading the content. There is only one quite quick file read. Within this view adding more subfilters effects only the already loaded items, and iterating this items is reasonably affordable.

Updating the data is also quite effective, only files that are subject to change are updated. A SQLite database can maintain the dates of all activities which have a expiry date, it can dynamically build it's own JSON file for the upcoming seven days or month. This will make the calendar view quite smooth for most usage. Picking future dates will be a nightmare though.

Still the map is an issue...

If you have read all of this, thank you. If you have experience with something similar, or might be onto something, feel free to reply! I have to quit writing, quit coding and start sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the crappy monglodb docs. I developed it for some internal projects and really wanted to share it with the community, but the lack of docs does make it hard to use. But great news I have docs now lol also slimmed down and cleaned up the source code. Hope it works better for you now. http://monglodb.com

Comment: Good to hear this, for my current project, trying MongloDB will not be an option anymore. But I will check it out again for future projects!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the original author of [JSONDB](https://github.com/irlgaming/jsondb-public) and thought I'd drop in and provide an answer for anyone finding this question via Googlefu.

JSONDB is now deprecated software - it's been replaced by another project called [SculeJS](https://github.com/dan-eyles/sculejs). SculeJS aims to provide a full featured NoSQL database written in pure JavaScript for use in Titanium, NodeJS, and web apps.

JSONDB was originally only available for use in iOS applications due to limitations in the way Ti native modules were built - the current versions of JSONDB and SculeJS are compatible with both iOS and Android apps.

In a lot of ways MongloDB and SculeJS are similar, where they diverge is in the way SculeJS has been engineered. SculeJS is intended more to provide powerful, generic data structures with a rich query layer rather than being a straight port of MongoDB. No insult to Monglo - it looks like great software, I just wanted to point out the difference in intent between the two projects.

As a side note - all pure JavaScript modules are limited to to a single execution context within Titanium applications.

For what you're building I think MongloDB, JSONDB, SculeJS and TaffyDB would all do the job, the details of the implementation would just be slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same problem. I had about 5mb's of data which I wanted to store with the app, and not let it download.

I finally ended up with an SQLite database, with high performance. It is not as bad as you think. It might not be a nice solution ,but for the lack of choice it is a very good one IMHO.

Just create a couple of tables, and functions to parse them to database, and the other way around, and I promise you, you will be happy.

DO NOT store the JSON in the database, but store the values appropriately.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your response. How fast can you fetch based upon criteria, like date needs to be between this and that, or only one category. Also when setting up a table, there is no certainty how much columns there will be needed, this is dependable on the type of activity. Is it a wise decision to start out with more columns than you might need?

Comment: no, you need to build a proper database. Use coupling tables for that, that way you don't need to specify a certain amount of colums. Look up tutorials on that. Make sure you also set proper indexes and stuff.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with doing this. I understand basic CRUD, do you know any resources or have any starting points?